# Parse error before '(' token

Tags: c, compiler-errors

So I have written down this program to read an input of unvariable length in C. The code is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct ch{  
   char c;
   struct ch *next;
} *first;

struct Member {
   char *name1,*name2;
   struct Member *Next;
} *FName;

int scan(void);
int main()
{
    first=NULL;
    FName=NULL;
    scan();
    return 0;
}

int scan(void)
{
    int M,i,count;
    struct ch *O;
    O=(struct ch *)malloc(sizeof(struct ch));
    O=first;
    scanf("%d",&M);

    for(i=0;i<M;i++)
    while(scanf("%c",&first->c))
    {
        O=first->next;
        if(first->c==' ')
            if(!count)
            {
                struct Member *oldfirst;
                oldfirst=(struct Member *)malloc(sizeof(struct Member));
            oldfirst=FName;
            FName->name1=(char *)malloc((count+1)*sizeof(char));
            for(i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                *FName->(name1+i)=first->c;     /*Error*/
                first=first->next;
            }
            *FName->(name1+count)='\0';         /*Error*/
            FName->Next=oldfirst;
            first=NULL;
            count=0;
        }
    if(first->c=='\n')
        if(!count)
        {
            FName->name2=(char *)malloc((count+1)*sizeof(char));
            for(i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                *FName->(name2+i)=first->c;     /*Error*/
                first=first->next;
            }
            *FName->(name2+count)='\0';         /*Error*/
            first=NULL;
            count=0;
        }

    O=first;
    count++;
}

return 0;
}
```

This is a part of the problem where I first need to take 2*M strings with two strings on each line separated by a space.

On compiling with GCC , I get the error: "parse error before '(' token". This error appears in 4 lines and I have marked them out in the code above. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3):

The `->` operator denotes accessing members of a pointer to a struct. E.g.

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} foo;

foo myFoo;
foo *fooPtr = &myFoo;
myFoo->a = 1;
```

Instead of the line:

```
*FName->(name2+count)='\0';
```

You probably want one of the following:

```
*(FName->name2 + count) = '\0';
FName->name2[count] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> *FName->(name1+i)
> ```

That's just illegal syntax. You probably want something like:

```
*(FName->name1 + i) = ...
```

---

Or as Harry points in a different answer, the more sane:

```
FName->name1[i] = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
FName->name1[i]=first->c;
```

Comment: Can you add some additional explanation about why this would resolve the parsing issue?